# Performance Trace of Program

Tags: linux, performance

I have a short-running program and once I run it, I need to record its CPU utilization and at the end I need to know its total instruction count. I went through some perf tools available for Linux but they did not satisfy my need. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `perf` was suitable for my need. As I was running the code in a VM, the vCPU had no performance counters; hence `perf` was showing me the `not supported` as value for the pertinent field. Running the program directly on the machine solved the issue.